# How to get Connection from DataSoruce with UserName and Password

Tags: java, oracle, datasource

Weblogic and java to connect with DataBase.

I have created an `Initialcontext` and then `lookfor` datasource. I have also created one datasource in `weblogic` under JDBC service.  Now problem is it looks datasource successfully, But when it call `getConnection(username, password)` then it throw an error, and authentication failed.

One important thing i have treated username and password as oracle user not as as table entry user. So when I go to directly Oracle and login as same user then it does not so any error.

Even if `datasource.getConnection()` called then it also working fine.

Can someone help me what's wrong with datasource when username and password is password.

```
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
      DataSource dataSource = null;
      try 
      {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();      
        dataSource = (DataSource)ic.lookup((String)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/datasource"));

      } catch (NamingException ex) 
      {
        throw new EJBException(ex);
      }
      return dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Failed to be authenticated?

Comment: What is in your datasoruce entry?

Comment: there is one datasource called jdbc/testDS in weblogic under JDBC services

Comment: what does `(String)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/datasource")` return?  It's possible it's not giving you `jdbc/testDS`.  Try looking up the datasource without looking up the jndi name first: `datasource = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/testDS");`